# Inputting one line at a time into a string array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file

New to both programming and Stackoverflow here. Just had a question about programming a portion of a class hangman program.

In order to start it off early, I'd have to hard code the answers in manually and set it to pick one at random like so:

```
srand(time(NULL));
string Phrases[3] = {"evan almighty","the hunger games","click"};
string SecretWord = Phrases[rand()%3];
```

I'm trying to use a txt file as an easier way to modify the answer list rather than cluttering up my main code (as recommended by my prof).

So, I was advised to use getline and a loop:

```
string Phrases[10];
ifstream fin("hangman.txt");
for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
{
    getline (fin, Phrases[x]);
}
string SecretWord = Phrases[rand()%10]
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering if there's any way to avoid hardcoding the total number of answers/phrases.

This is all done in CodeBlocks, using int main(), and return 0, just for context.

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at std::vector (a growable array)

Answer (score 1):

**Dynamic Memory Allocation**

Lets assume our array is an `int array[3]` 
You say that you want a memory size of `3*sizeof(int)` to the operating system You determine the size of the array before run time. 
In this example you determine the array size on compile time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i,n;
  int * p;
  cout << "How many numbers would you like to type? ";
  cin >> i;
  p= new (nothrow) int[i];
  if (p == nullptr)
    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";
  else
  {
    for (n=0; n<i; n++)
    {
      cout << "Enter number: ";
      cin >> p[n];
    }
    cout << "You have entered: ";
    for (n=0; n<i; n++)
      cout << p[n] << ", ";
    delete[] p;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> How many numbers would you like to type? 5
>   Enter number : 75
>   Enter number : 436
>   Enter number : 1067
>   Enter number : 8
>   Enter number : 32
>   You have entered: 75, 436, 1067, 8, 32,

This example is taken from :http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Or you can use data types like `std::list`, `std::stack`, `std::vector`...

Example for stack:

```
stack<string> slist;
slist.add("stack");
slist.add("a");
slist.add("am");
slist.add("i");
for(i=0;stack.size();i++)
cout << stack.pop()<< " ";
```

Output:

> i am a stack

Comment: I do appreciate you aggregating the options. For a simple program like this would you recommend a linecount grab as Emile suggested? edit: sorry, did not realize that enter actually entered the comment. I admit I'll have to look over cplusplus.com to see if I can learn about dynamic memory and the other options. (Sorry, first year in programming)

Comment: @gameindians of course his solution is good but with that solution you still need to define the arrays size before the program runs i tought you ask that

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to count the number of lines in your text file. This can be achieved a bit like this:

```
ifstream file("hangman.txt");
string line;
int lineCount = 0;

while (getline(file, line))
    lineCount++;

file.close();
```

After this bit of code, lineCount will contain the number of lines in your text file, which should be the number of answers.

Of course, if you have blank lines in your file, you might want to add an if statement to the loop, in order to check if there truly is an answer on the line before incrementing the counter.

Comment: Tried this out and it looks like it works! Would the empty line correction statement be like:

    int emptyline = 0;
    if line = "";
        emptyline++;

within the loop and at the end:

    linecount=linecount-emptyline;

Comment: This would work, but a simpler way would be to simply put the original lineCount++ in the if.
Example:
`ifstream file("hangman.txt");
string line;
int lineCount = 0;

while (getline(file, line))
   if (line.length > 0)
    lineCount++;

file.close();`